# insert object in array using push method

Tags: javascript, arrays, push

```
var dd = [];
const ff = { };
ff.dd = 0;
dd.push(ff);
console.log(dd);
ff.dd = 1;
dd.push(ff);
console.log(dd);
```

I am getting output

```
[ { dd: 0 } ]
[ { dd: 1 }, { dd: 1 } ]
```

but I want the output to be like

```
[ { dd: 0 } ]
[ { dd: 0 }, { dd: 1 } ]
```

Comment: Strongly recommend not using the same identifier (`dd`) for two entirely different things when asking questions, it makes both the question and its potential answers unnecessarily complicated.

Answer (score 1):

To get that output, you'd have to create a **new** object (`ff`), instead of modifying the existing one.

```js
var dd = [];
let ff = { };     // <== `let` instead of `const`
ff.dd = 0;
dd.push(ff);
console.log(dd);
ff = { };         // <== Create a new object
ff.dd = 1;
dd.push(ff);
console.log(dd);
```

---

Side note: You don't need `ff` at all:

```js
var dd = [];
dd.push({dd: 0});
dd.push({dd: 1});
console.log(dd);
```

...and in fact the whole thing can be done in one initializer:

```js
var dd = [
  {dd: 0},
  {dd: 1}
];
console.log(dd);
```

Comment: But i should use one object for assign data .what should i do?

Comment: @viswaram: You *can't* use just one object; the output you want clearly shows an array with *two* objects in it with different contents (different `dd` properties).

Answer (score 1):

Javascript keeps references to objects.
In your code, you initially push the `ff` variable with `dd` set to 0.
Then you modify the `dd` value of the same `ff` variable and push another reference to it into the array.
That is why you get an array with 2 references to the same `ff` object with `dd` value of 1.

If you want to achieve the result you wrote you need to create a new object before pushing it again into the array.

Answer (score 1):

If your `ff` always is of one level deep, you can use [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to clone `ff` each time you put it into the array.

```
var ffCopy = Object.assign({}, ff);
```

---

```js
var dd = [];
const ff = { };
ff.dd = 0;
dd.push(Object.assign({}, ff));
console.log(dd);
ff.dd = 1;
dd.push(Object.assign({}, ff));
console.log(dd);
```